# How to prevent component from rendering after animation in react

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have got a component which displays a hint only a single time to each user. Lets call it `<Hint />`.

While rendering the component, I am looking for a `confirmed: boolean`. If its `false`, the component should render. If `true`, the component should not render at all.

Thats done easily using

```
function Hint(confirmed: boolean) {
   if(confirmed) return null;
   return (
      <Example>
          <Text>I am a super helpful hint.</Text>
          <Button title="Okay" onClick={this.hideHint} />
      </Example>
}
```

But turns out, my `<Example />` has a beautiful fade-out animation I want to keep and display.

How can I tell my `<Hint />` component to not render at all if `confirmed === true`, but keep it if it was `false` and gets `true`, to keep the animation?

Can I use something like `ComponentDidMount()`? I feel very insecure using the lifecycle methods from react native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** is a **stateless Components**, it'll be re-rendered each time his parent renders.

If you want to avoid multiple re-renders you can implement a **stateful component**, that'll only re-render when you change the props or the state of the component.

For even more control on the re-render, you can implement the [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) method in your statefull component.